# How to check element with multiple classes for a number in class

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is it posible to get the class name in this element if its a number?
Can you check if this element has a number as a class and get it out ?

```
<button id="12" class="btn btn-default 1000 tBtn">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the attribute selector, `[class]`, to select all elements with class attributes. From there you can filter the selected elements based on whether the the array of classes contain a number as a value by using the [`$.isNumeric` jQuery method](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isNumeric/):

```
var $elements = $('[class]').filter(function () {
  var classes = this.className.split(' ');
  var classesWithNumbers = classes.filter(function (value) {
    return $.isNumeric(value);
  });

  return classesWithNumbers.length;
});
```

Here is a shorter, less verbose version:

```
var $elements = $('[class]').filter(function () {
  return this.className.split(' ').filter($.isNumeric).length;
});
```

It's worth mentioning that as of HTML4 classes and ids cannot start with numbers. However, that is no longer the case with HTML5. For reference, see: [What are valid values for the id attribute in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Comment: Thanks for the help

Comment: i came here yesterday to refer to your solution and i must have unchecked your answer by mistake...